# Speed-up Sqlalchemy query with subqueries to check existence of related rows

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have query in SQLAlchemy that is structurally the same as the MWE below, which I am using to query a Sqlite DB.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from timeit import timeit
import os.path
from tqdm import tqdm
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import date, timedelta
from random import choice, randint
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column, Integer, Date, String, ForeignKey, sql, orm, create_engine)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


SAVE_INTERVAL = 365
START_DATE = date(2015, 1, 1)
DATE_RANGE = SAVE_INTERVAL * 5
NUM_AS = 10000
NAME_RANGE = NUM_AS // 4
NUM_BS = NUM_AS // 4


Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    save_date = Column(Date)

    def __init__(self, name, save_date):
        self.name = name
        self.save_date = save_date

    bs = relationship('B', back_populates='a')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A({}, {})'.format(self.name,
                                  self.save_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))


class B(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))

    # Relationships
    a = relationship('A', back_populates='bs')

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


db_path = os.path.expanduser('~/test-query{}.db'.format(NUM_AS))

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + db_path)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

if not os.path.exists(db_path):
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    print("Generating test data")
    # Create dummy As and Bs data

    a_list = []
    for _ in tqdm(range(NUM_AS), "Generating As"):
        a = A('name{:03}'.format(randint(1, NAME_RANGE)),
              START_DATE + timedelta(days=randint(0, DATE_RANGE)))
        a_list.append(a)
        session.add(a)
        session.commit()

    for _ in tqdm(range(NUM_BS), "Generating Bs"):
        session.add(B(choice(a_list)))
        session.commit()


# Create query for sessions that still need to be reported
A_alias = orm.aliased(A)
query = (
    session.query(A)
    .filter(
        # Filter out rows of the same name that have newer versions
        ~(session.query(A_alias.id)
          .filter(
              A_alias.name == A.name,
              A_alias.save_date > A.save_date).exists()),
        # Filter out rows that have older versions are referenced
        # in table B that were saved less than SAVE_INTERVAL days earlier
        ~(session.query(A_alias.id)
          .join(B)  # Only select sessions with a report
          .filter(
              A_alias.name == A.name,
              (sql.func.abs(
                  sql.func.julianday(A.save_date) -
                  sql.func.julianday(A_alias.save_date)) <=
               SAVE_INTERVAL)).exists())))

print(query)


def count():
    query.count()


print("Calculating exec time...")
print('{} s'.format(timeit(count, number=1)))


pprint("Number of returned records {}".format(count()))
```

It works fine, but is a bit slow on the production database (which is around 8,000 rows) making the web-page sluggish.

So I am wondering whether there is way I can speed it up, either by altering the SQL or how the ORM objects are generated?

Comment: This appears to return no records when run, or am I missing something?

Comment: Did the test DB get created properly? If it was interrupted the first time then it won’t be created on subsequent runs as it checks to see if the file exists